# Balance brackets by swapping

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a string containing characters `(` and `)`. For example `)()(())(`, find the minimum swaps needed to make it balanced. We can swap any character, they need not be adjacent. If it is not possible return -1.

So for `)()(())(` we can swap first and last character to make it balanced string `(()(()))` so number of swaps is 1. So answer is `1`.

Length of string can be `1 to 10^5`

Here is my code:

```
public static int solve(String s) {
  while(true) {
    int pos = s.indexOf("()");
    if(pos == -1) break;
    s = s.substring(0, pos) + s.substring(pos+2);
  }
  int open = 0, close = 0;
  for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == '(') open++;
    else close++;
  }
  if(open == close) return open;
  return -1;
}
```

This is not efficient approach in terms of time complexity. How can we solve this in less time complexity?

Comment: If the code works, as far as I know, the question should be at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One useful observation is that when the number of opening and closing brackets is equal, there is always a solution.

Secondly, when there is a solution, we just need to count the number of closing brackets that have no corresponding opening bracket: these can always be swapped with an opening bracket that follows later in the string to make a valid sequence. There is no need to actually find that opening bracket, nor to actually perform the swap.

So a working algorithm should only need to keep track of the balance, and when it becomes negative, count that as a swap:

```
    public static int solve(String s) {
        int balance = 0;
        int numSwaps = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            balance += s.charAt(i) == '(' ? 1 : -1;
            if (balance < 0) { // Unmatched closing
                balance = 0;
                numSwaps++;
            }
        }
        return balance == numSwaps ? numSwaps : -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I add sample code below.

```java
public class MinSwaps {
    public static int solve(String s) {
        int opens = 0;
        int closes = 0;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '(') {
                opens++;
            } else {
                if(opens>0)opens--;
                else closes++;
            }
        }

        if(opens==closes) return opens;
        return -1;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = ")()(())(";
        int result = solve(input);
        System.out.println("Minimum swaps needed: " + result);
    }
}
```

`opens`: It represents the count of unmatched opening parentheses encountered during the iteration.

`closes`: It represents the count of unmatched closing parentheses encountered during the iteration.

These variables are used to keep track of the unmatched parentheses while iterating through the input string.

The function returns the count of unmatched opening parentheses if it matches the count of unmatched closing parentheses; otherwise, it returns -1.

In the example `)()(())(`, the function would return 1, indicating 1 unmatched opening parentheses and closing parentheses.

Comment: for input `)()(())(` output is `1`, please test the answer with this input and see if it works. Also add comments to code to understand.

Comment: I changed my answer. I made mistake while optimizing codelines. sorry.

Comment: why 2? I want to know how result should be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Stack to keep track of the open pairs:

```
import java.util.Stack;  

public class MyClass {
    public static int solve(String s) {
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
        int opens = 0;
        int closes = 0;
        
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == '(') {
                //  open a pair to be resolved
                st.push(c);
                opens++;
            } else {
                if (st.empty() || (st.peek() == ')')) {
                    //  can't resolve, have to store
                    st.push(c);
                    closes++;
                } else {
                    //  resolve one pair
                    st.pop();
                    opens--;
                }
            }
        }

        if (opens == closes) {
            return opens;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = ")()(";
        int result = solve(input);
        
        if (result == -1) {
            System.out.println("swapping not feasible");
        } else if (result == 0) {
            System.out.println("brackets are balanced");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Minimum swaps needed: " + result);
        }
    }
}
```